# How to find out which file or folder is being locked by process in Windows OS?

Tags: windows, process, lock

Once in a while, I run the task manager and see several processes with the same name (e.g. comskip) running at the same time in the background while looping or using most of computation power (because it is dealing with a corrupt file). I know the exact folder from which that process is using files from, but there are just too many files in that folder that It would take me days to go through each file and determine the process that locks them (which I know how to do). My concern: I would like to reverse this way of establishing that relationship. From a known running process in the task manager, I would like to determine the file that that process has locked and not the other way arround.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Microsoft/**[SysInternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)**.

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Process Explorer to see which handles a process has opened (when you select a process) and use "**Find**" to search for a file and see what processes have that file opened.